# Event Sourcing and CQRS

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

Is there any industry standard framework available in the market for implementing Event Sourcing and CQRS (Command Query Responsibility Segregation) ?

Comment: I recommend implementing your own. In my experience it is harder to work through all abstractions of the framework than writing your own solution. The hardest parts would probably be aggregate snapshotting and event versioning. The db integration layer might be a bit tricky to get right as well if you need to guarantee optimistic concurrency. Simply using a framework won't make it easier. It'll simply hide the complexities and defer problems until you actually have them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Axon framework](http://axonframework.org) in java
and [Prooph](https://github.com/prooph) in php.

Answer (score 1):

For node.js environment where is two major frameworks which are actual maintained nowadays - [ReSolve](https://github.com/reimagined/resolve) and [Wolkenkit](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit). These frameworks also contain integrated solutions for communication with front-end web page (SPA application).

There are back-end only libraries for eventsourcing for node.js, including [Node-Eventstore](https://github.com/adrai/node-eventstore) and [Node-cqrs](https://github.com/snatalenko/node-cqrs#readme), but it's more libraries than frameworks for production applications.

Answer (score 1):

Note that I recommended to implement your own Framework in the comment above. However I can still refer you to **Akka**. Akka is an actor model implementation that comes with support for event sourcing. It is available for **.NET**, **Scala** and **Java**:

See:
https://getakka.net/articles/intro/what-is-akka.html (.NET)
https://akka.io/docs/ (Scala & Java)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up..I have explored some features of Akka. Lightbend has an opinionated framework called Lagom build on top pf Akka which has out of the box support for CQRS and event sourcing.
https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.2.x/java/ES_CQRS.html